# Forward declaration of C++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to add some friend declarations to a class. For example, I want to add some functions of `operator==` ,`operator <`. So what I have to do is use the forward declarations:

```
template <typename >
class MyBlob;

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const MyBlob<T> &, const MyBlob<T>&);

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(const MyBlob<T> &, const MyBlob<T>&);


template <typename T>
bool operator<(const MyBlob<T> &, const MyBlob<T>&);


template <typename T>
class MyBlob
{

    friend bool operator== <T>(const MyBlob<T> &lhs,const MyBlob<T> &rhs);
    friend bool operator!= <T>(const MyBlob<T> &lhs,const MyBlob<T> &rhs);
    friend bool operator< <T>(const MyBlob<T> &lhs,const MyBlob<T> &rhs);
      //other things

};
```

This is annoying that I have to use `template <typename T>` for three times. And this really reduce the readability.

So, is there any method to make the  forward declaration more simple? Or can I have some method to declare these things in one place just like the ordinary function?
If this can't be done, Is using `typedef` to simplify the `template <typename T>` a good idea?

Comment: You aren't befriending those templates you declared, just so you know.

Comment: Oh sorry for forgetting the  `const` in class body. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Sut - No, even with the `const`. Try a more complete example, you'll hit an undefined function error. It's an intricate point in the language, and somewhat maddening.

Comment: @Sut, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829633/434551 to understand the point StoryTeller is trying to make.

Comment: OK, I get it, That's really disappointed. So I have to define the `template` every time. But if I have too many friend functions, is it a good way to just define a friend class containing every function instead?

Comment: Thank you all. I forget to put the `<T>` in it. I do get the error. Thanks!~

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining friend operators within the class declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class MyBlob {

    friend bool operator== (const MyBlob& lhs, const MyBlob& rhs) {
        // ...
    }

    friend bool operator!= (const MyBlob& lhs, const MyBlob& rhs) {
        // ...
    }

    friend bool operator< (const MyBlob& lhs, const MyBlob& rhs) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```